# Displaying multidimensional array in Django

Tags: python, arrays, django, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to display a multidimensional array in a template through Django but I can't seem to loop through each row/col. I manage to print it out but it comes out like this which has the brackets because I'm just printing out the object:

[image]

But I need it to come out like this:

[image]

This is my class:

```
class VigenereCipher:

    squareAlphabet = []
    letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    def __init__(self):
        self.squaredAlphabet=[ [ 'A' for x in range(26)] for j in range(26)]
        #print(self.squaredAlphabet)
        for x in range(len(self.letters)):
        #    self.squaredAlphabet[x][x] = self.letters[x]
            # print(self.squaredAlphabet[x][x])
            #print(x)
            j = 0
            for y in range(len(self.letters)):
                #print(x)
                j = y + x
                #print(j)
                if(j > 5):
                    j = j - 26
                #print(j)
            #   print(self.letters[j])
                self.squaredAlphabet[x][y] = self.letters[j]
                #print(self.squaredAlphabet[x][j])
        #print(self.squaredAlphabet)
                # if ((y + x) > 5):
                #     y = y - 5
                # #print(self.letters[y])
                # self.squaredAlphabet[x][y] = self.letters[y]
        for x in range(len(self.squaredAlphabet)):
            for y in range(len(self.squaredAlphabet)):
                print("Position: x", x, "y",  y, "=",  self.squaredAlphabet[x][y])

    def getSquaredAlphabet(self):
        return self.squaredAlphabet
```

Views.py:

```
def vigenereHome(request):
    object = VigenereCipher()
    x = object.getSquaredAlphabet()
    return render(request, "VigenereCipher.html", {'x' : x})
```

And the template is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "CryptoWeb/css/VigenereCSS.css" %}"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "CryptoWeb/css/bootstrap.css" %}"/>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "CryptoWeb/js/VigenereJavascript.js" %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "CryptoWeb/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
  <title>Vigenere Cipher</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    {% for i in x %}
<tr>
  <td>
  <div <div align='center'><font face='arial' size='1'>

{# {% load VigenereTags %}#}
{# {{i|index:0}}#}
{{i}}
</font>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: 
I know that I can print it out using `{{i.0}}` and so on but there must be a way to loop through `i` without having to write it down literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's because each `i` is a row and it requires an additional loop. Here's a small example: `arr = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]` and I want to print every element separately `a b c d e f`:

```
for x in arr:
    for y in x:
        print y
```